# how to detect touches ended UIPickerView Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I would like to be able to detect when a user lifts their finger off a UIPickerView control in iOS using Swift uikit. This needs to occur even if they do not scroll the control or change the selected index - so i cannot user UIPIckerView didselectrow.

I am using a hitTest to determine touch begin but I can not figure out how to get touch ended. I have tried using gesturerecognizer but whilst i can get a tap, or taps, or swipe , or pan I cant seem to get anything i could use as a touch end event.

As background I am using a timer to automatically hide a view and i want to suspend it whilst the control is in use.